# Pinging example.com results in PING example.com.com

Tags: dns, vps

I'm setting up an unmanaged VPS of mine.
I have created two A records at my domain name registrar to point example.com to my ip, and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to my ip.

My /etc/hostname has example.com in it.

When I ping from inside my ssh, the output becomes like this:

ping example.com
PING example.com.com (ip here) ...

(example.com is just an example here; in reality i'm using my own domain name)

But when I ping google.com for instance, I get

ping google.com
PING google.com (...

My question is: why is an extra ".com" added when I pinged my own server and why does it hang there? Doing a dig example.com  +short resulted in nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) for the status of DNS propagation. If all ok, then check your firewall settings, see [here](https://www.crybit.com/iptables-rules-for-icmp/) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the useful link.  Is it normal to be getting all X in the propagation checker? It's been a few hours.

Comment: Then it is not existent (correct entered) and/or not yet propagated. Propagation might take in extreme cases up to 72 hours

Comment: yeah. i keyed them wrongly. lol.